# get image width with help of Jquery validation plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

i have some basic knowledge in jquery,
i want to validate image width with jquery validation plugins ,for that i used addmethod to create custom method called as "imgwidth" see example..i got some example to get file size with help of custom method..but i want image width with custom method....thx in advance....

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 
 $.validator.addMethod("imgwidth", function (value, element, param) {

   alert(value);
   alert('i want get here image width')
  
  }, "Please ");

    //validation implementation will go here.
 $('#form_id').validate({
  errorClass:"errermsg",
  rules:{
       
         file:{
             required: true,
          imgwidth: 500,
        }
  },
  messages:
  { 
   file:
   {   
   required:"</br>Please Enter File",
   imgwidth:"</br>width 500px",    
   }
  }, 
  submitHandler: function (form) {
   //jQuery("#lodding_cont").css('display','inline-block');
   var form_data = jQuery(form).serialize(); 
   var file_path = "check.php"; 
   
   jQuery.ajax({
           url: file_path,
           type: "POST",
          data:form_data,
          success:function(data){
       
     if(data){
      //jQuery("#lodding_cont").css('display','none');
     }
      else{
       alert('not');
      }
       }            
         });
   
  }
  
  
 }); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form name="form" id="form_id" action="" method="post">
 <table border="1">
     <tr>
            <td class="input"> 
            <input type="file" name="file"  id="file1"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
         <td>
             <input type="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>                
    </table>
 
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Element.clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientWidth)
2. [Element.clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientHeight)

   ```
   var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
   //or however you get a handle to the IMG
   var width = img.clientWidth;
   var height = img.clientHeight;
   ```

this might be work for u. try this

hope This [Ref](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/35p9pz7z/) can work

Comment: it returns 235 every time when alert varialble "width"..but my uploaded image width was 1024 x 768..:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
var width = $('#yourIMAGEID').width();
```

Or

```
var width = $('#yourIMAGEID').attr('width');
```